# Why did the two seperate chart components squeeze into the same box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am making a dashboard using `React.js` and `d3.js`. I encountered this intriguing problem that had confused me for hours.

Here is the `Scatterplot.js` written in `d3.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import * as d3 from "d3"
import { ceil, floor } from "lodash"
import "./scatterplot.css"

export default class Scatterplot extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: "Level 1",
      category: "Status",
      yAxisAttribute: "YoY Growth Rate",
      xAxisAttribute: "Social Popularity",
      width: 700,
      height: 500,
    }
    this.chartRef = React.createRef()
    this.drawChart = this.drawChart.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawChart()
  }

  drawChart() {

    // Helper functions

    const calcMean = arr => {
      const reducer = (total, currentValue) => total + currentValue
      const sum = arr.reduce(reducer)
      return sum / arr.length
    }

    // Regarding data

    const { data } = this.props

    const xMin = floor(
      data.reduce(
        (a, b) => a["Social Popularity"] < b["Social Popularity"] ? a : b
      )["Social Popularity"],
      1
    )
    const xMax = ceil(
      data.reduce(
        (a, b) => a["Social Popularity"] > b["Social Popularity"] ? a : b
      )["Social Popularity"],
      1
    )

    const xAvg = calcMean(data.map(d => d["Social Popularity"]))

    const yMin = floor(
      data.reduce(
        (a, b) => a["YoY Growth Rate"] < b["YoY Growth Rate"] ? a : b
      )["YoY Growth Rate"],
      1
    )

    const yMax = ceil(
      data.reduce(
        (a, b) => a["YoY Growth Rate"] > b["YoY Growth Rate"] ? a : b
      )["YoY Growth Rate"],
      1
    )

    const yAvg = calcMean(data.map(d => d["YoY Growth Rate"]))

    // Config Chart

    const margin = {
      top: 50,
      right: 50,
      bottom: 50,
      left: 50
    }

    const width = this.state.width - margin.left - margin.right
    const height = this.state.height - margin.top - margin.bottom
    const offset = 10

    const svg = d3.select(".Chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`
      )

    // Add background image

    svg.append("svg:defs")
      .append("svg:pattern")
      .attr("id", "background")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49921469713_111b7c41da_o.png")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)

    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "url(#background)")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-dasharray", "1000")

    // Add tags

    const topLeftTag = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")

    topLeftTag.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 120)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("class", "rect-tag")

    topLeftTag.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 6)
      .attr("dy", 14)
      .text("Small and Emerging")
      .attr("class", "rect-tag-text")

    const topRightTag = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(470, 0)`)

    topRightTag.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 130)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("class", "rect-tag")

    topRightTag.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 6)
      .attr("dy", 14)
      .text("Popular and Growing")
      .attr("class", "rect-tag-text")

    const bottomLeftTag = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, 380)`)

    bottomLeftTag.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("class", "rect-tag")

    bottomLeftTag.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 5)
      .attr("dy", 14)
      .text("Small and Stable")
      .attr("class", "rect-tag-text")

    const bottomRightTag = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(485, 380)`)

    bottomRightTag.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 115)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("class", "rect-tag")

    bottomRightTag.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 5)
      .attr("dy", 14)
      .text("Popular and Stable")
      .attr("class", "rect-tag-text")

    // Add X axis
    const x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([xMin, xMax])
      .range([0, width])

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
      .attr("class", "axis x")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0).tickFormat(d => `${d * 100}%`))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")

    // X axis label

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("x", width / 2 + offset * 2)
      .attr("y", height + margin.bottom / 2 + offset)
      .text("Social Popularity")

    // Add Y axis

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([yMin, yMax * 1.1])
      .range([height, 0])

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis-y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0).tickFormat(d => `${d * 100}%`))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")

    // Y axis label
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("x", margin.top - height / 2)
      .attr("y", -margin.left + offset * 1.5)
      .text("YoY Growth Rate")

    // Add horizontal line

    svg.append("line")
      .attr("class", "avg-line")
      .attr("x1", 0)
      .attr("y1", y(yAvg))
      .attr("x2", width)
      .attr("y2", y(yAvg))

    // Add vertical line
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("class", "avg-line")
      .attr("x1", x(xAvg))
      .attr("y1", 0)
      .attr("x2", x(xAvg))
      .attr("y2", height)

    // Color scale

    const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(["Growing", "Declining", "Stable", "Seasonal", "Hot Topic"])
      .range(["#4ca457", "#b12318", "#7f7f7f", "#9b6b23", "#334a74"])

    const points = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(data, d => d["Level 1"])
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d["Social Popularity"])}, ${y(d["YoY Growth Rate"])})`)

    points.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .style("fill", d => colors(d["Status"]))

    points.append("text")
      .attr("class", "annotation")
      .attr("dy", -10)
      .text(d => d["Level 1"])


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Chart" ref={this.chartRef}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The code above draws a chart that looks that this:

[image]

The intriguing problem occured when I tried to pass the same chart component (i.e `Scatterplot.js`) to `App.js` in `React.js`. Here is `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react"
import "react-bulma-components/dist/react-bulma-components.min.css";
import { Section, Container, Heading, Columns, Box } from "react-bulma-components"
import Scatterplot from "./charts/Scatterplot.js"
import "./App.sass"
import "./App.css"

export default class App extends Component {

    state = {
        passionPoint1: null,
        passionPoint2: null,
        passionPoint3: null,
        isLoading: true
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/dashboard")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({
                author: data.author,
                passionPoints1: JSON.parse(data.level1_data),
                passionPoints2: JSON.parse(data.level2_data),
                passionPoints3: JSON.parse(data.level3_data),
            }))
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, passionPoints1, passionPoints2, passionPoints3 } = this.state
        if (isLoading) {
            return null
        } else {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <Section size="small">
                        <Container>
                            <Heading>The chart takes up Box 1, which is what I expected</Heading>
                            <Heading subtitle>
                                By Author
                            </Heading>
                        </Container>
                    </Section>
                    <Section size="small">
                        <Columns>
                            <Columns.Column size={7}>
                                <Box>
                                    <Scatterplot data={passionPoints1} />
                                </Box>
                            </Columns.Column>
                            <Columns.Column size={5}>
                                <Box>
                                    <p>Box 2</p>
                                </Box>
                            </Columns.Column>
                            <Columns.Column size={7}>
                                <Box>
                                    <p>Box 3</p>
                                </Box>
                            </Columns.Column>
                            <Columns.Column size={5}>
                                <Box>
                                    <p>Box 4</p>
                                </Box>
                            </Columns.Column>
                        </Columns>
                    </Section>
                </Fragment>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The dashboard now looks like this, which is what I expected.

[image]

However, in `App.js`, if I replace

```
                        <Box>
                            <p>Box 3</p>
                        </Box>
```

with

```
                        <Box>
                            <Scatterplot data={passionPoints1} />
                        </Box>
```

The new chart did not take up the space of Box 3, instead, it merged with the chart in Box 1. It looks like this:

[image]

I find this very annoying. What I want is a new chart that takes up the space of Box 3 instead of merging with Box 1.

I have tried other front-end frameworks like `material-ui` and `ant-design` and the same problem occurred as well. Here `bulma` is only one of the cases I have tried. I also tried different data source but the same problem still occured. I have tried assigning different ids to the chart div but it did not help. Can anybody explain why this happened and is there any solution to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.select(".Chart")` will select an element with the class 'Chart'.  It's finding your first div with that class, nothing in d3 is scoped to your component.  You need to find a different way to get the element.  You probably want to use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }

  drawChart() {
    ...
    const svg = d3.select(this.myRef.current)
      .append("svg")
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and solution! It really helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
const svg = d3.select(".Chart")
```

always selects first element with class Chart in dom (which is first box). try to use more specific selector for the container.